# json/jquery to second div returns NaN

Tags: php, jquery, json, nan

I'm fetching a row of data from a mysql-server using php, then encode it to a json array. I then pull the information using the following PHP. The strange part is that if I send "vname" to it's own div, I get "NaN" as a result. If I display it in the first div, everything turns out fine. Any idea why? Btw, is it right of me to use .html to send to the div? I've tried .appendTo and .text with the same result.

```
<h3>Output: </h3>
<div id="output">Content1</div>
<div id="username">content2</div>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var id = data[0];
            var vname = data[1];
            var message = data[2];
            var timestamp = data[3];

            $('#output').html(+id + timestamp + message);
            $('#username').html(+vname);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: is that a typo that you have a plus sign (+) before vname in the last line? and all of the other variable names as well?

Comment: Which of your data[n] elements are supposed to be numbers and which are supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I;m going to guess its because of the first `+`. Javascript is trying to add nothing to all of the other stuff, which would output a `NaN`

```
 $('#output').html(id +timestamp +message );   
$('#username').html( vname );
```

In this case `text()` might be a better to use because there aren't any html elements in your strings, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: You where absolutely right. I'm new to this (surprise) - so I guess I have learnt that + adds vars when updating content to a specific div? Thank you!

Comment: `+` will add integers and strings together but since you have `*blank* +` javascript assigning is NaN because it needs something to add in the place of blank. Just so you know `NaN` stands for `Not a Number`

Comment: Thank you for clearifying and helping! You learn something every day, it's a luxury!

Comment: Thats why I love it! Good luck with everything

Comment: @locrizak It isn't "adding a blank" - it's a unary plus operator.  I have a link to the MDN article in my answer.

Comment: Yeah wrong words on my part, I was guessing it was something along those lines but didn't really know how to explain it properly, nice answer +1

Answer (score 3):

`+variable` is shorthand for casting a variable to a number: [Unary plus/minus (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29)

```
var x = "5";
+x; //Gives you 5 as a number
x = "Hello";
+x; //Gives you NaN
```

You can use regular [append](http://api.jquery.com/append).

```
$('#output').append(id + timestamp + message);
$('#username').append(vname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#output').html(+id + timestamp + message);
$('#username').html(+vname);
```

These are probably your problem. The plus sign in front of the variables would throw an error. If you are trying to concatenate (add together) the existing the value and your response from the ajax change it to some thing like this:

```
$('#output').html($('#output').html() + id + timestamp + message);
$('#username').html($('#username').html + vname);
```